# how to get column info mapped to pojo in room db in android

Tags: android

```
I m getting below warning and query not working

 @Query("SELECT emailId FROM table_contacts")
    public LiveData<List<ContactsEntity>> getAllEmailIdFromDB();

my entity:
@PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "contactId")
    private String contactId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber = null;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "emailId")
    private String emailId = null;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isContactsSynched")
    private String isContactsSynched = "false";
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isRegistered")
    private String isRegistered = "false";

warning:
ContactsEntityDao.java:35: warning:  com.enstage.wibmo.main.db.entities.ContactsEntity has some fields [contactId, phoneNumber, name, isContactsSynched, isRegistered] which are not returned by the query. If they are not supposed to be read from the result, you can mark them with @Ignore annotation. You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by the query: emailId. Fields in com.enstage.wibmo.main.db.entities.ContactsEntity: contactId, phoneNumber, emailId, name, isContactsSynched, isRegistered.
```

I have added column info for all field still i get warning nd query not working.

I want read column email id and name mapped to pojo. How to achieve this
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you need just e-mails you can get just a list of Strings by:

```
@Query("SELECT emailId FROM table_contacts")
public LiveData<List<String>> getAllEmailIdFromDB();
```

If you need the whole POJO from DAO you have to declare all fields in your request:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table_contacts")
public LiveData<List<ContactsEntity>> getAllEmailIdFromDB();
```

Comment: @Query("SELECT emailId FROM table_contacts") not working

Comment: @Query("SELECT emailId FROM table_contacts") if i want to get email column and name column mapped to pojo what will be the query?

Comment: i want name and email id for showing in adapter. how to write query for that which is mapped to pojo.

Comment: @Query("SELECT emailId,name FROM table_contacts WHERE isContactsSynched = :isContactsSynched")
    public LiveData<List<ContactsEntity>> getAllEmailIdFromDB(String isContactsSynched); doing like this will i get column values mapped to pojo?

Comment: Again. Decision depends on what you want to return by your query. If you want to get in your adapter more than one field of your POJO you can: 1. use "select * from table_contacts". That means that you want to get whole entity ContactsEntity with ALL it's fields (id, name whatever). 2. If on some reason (save memory allocated for this operation?) you want to get just two fields by your query, you have to declare another entity - another class that includes only these fields. Then you have to choose this new entity as a type of returning value. But I recommend for simplification try first way

Comment: @Query("SELECT phoneNumber FROM table_contacts WHERE isContactsSynched = :contactSynched LIMIT 50")
    public List<String> getAllPhoneNumbersNotSynched(String contactSynched); is this query correct i want to send phonenumber string array to api call in count of 50. i have modified my query above.if  on last iteration if i have 20 rows with phoneNumber will above query work?

Comment: @Query("SELECT emailId FROM table_contacts")
public LiveData<List<String>> getAllEmailIdFromDB(); not working

Comment: You can read [this reference](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#query-subset-cols) for second variant

Comment: i tried seeing above reference i got again same warning.

Comment: in above case my query is @Query("SELECT emailId,name FROM table_contacts WHERE isContactsSynched = :isContactsSynched")
    public LiveData<List<ContactsEntity>> getAllEmailIdFromDB(String isContactsSynched);

Comment: ContactsEntity has some fields [contactId, phoneNumber, isContactsSynched, isRegistered] which are not returned by the query. If they are not supposed to be read from the result, you can mark them with @Ignore annotation. You can suppress this warning by annotating the method with @SuppressWarnings(RoomWarnings.CURSOR_MISMATCH). Columns returned by the query: emailId, name. Fields in ContactsEntity: contactId, phoneNumber, emailId, name, isContactsSynched, isRegistered.
    public LiveData<List<ContactsEntity>> getAllEmailIdFromDB(String isContactsSynched);                                 ^

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't add anything more clear to my answers above

Comment: referring to ur reference above i tried to fetch two column that is email id and name in above case my query is @Query("SELECT emailId,name FROM table_contacts WHERE isContactsSynched = :isContactsSynched") public LiveData<List<ContactsEntity>> getAllEmailIdFromDB(String isContactsSynched);

Comment: getting same warning

Comment: what i m missing for warning i m not getting

Comment: Last try :-) For variant 2 as I wrote before "you have to declare ANOTHER entity - ANOTHER class that includes only these fields" So you have now only class ContactsEntity. But for returning just two fields make ANOTHER class, ContactsEmailNameEntity and use it as a returning type. Yes, it may seem overarchitecturing, but that is a point of this variant

Comment: @Query("SELECT emailId FROM table_contacts")
public LiveData<List<Str@Query("SELECT emailId FROM table_contacts")
public LiveData<List<String>> getAllEmailIdFromDB();ing>> getAllEmailIdFromDB(); is not working